# ANT Reading property from property files, using an ANT property

Tags: jenkins, ant, properties-file

simple question for you..

I have a property file with a value like this

```
 CommercialManager=MOT
 CommercialUser=AT
 CommercialAdmin=POT
```

I'm calling an Ant Script from Jenkins, passing some variables..
some of these variables are used to get a dynamic property from the property file..

I'm saying that if i select into the jenkins job the CommercialAdmin variable from a select list i want to get the property with that name.

The value selected into the Jenkins JOB is set inside a variable ROLE, that is passed to my ANT script..

Below my code:

```
<property file="Profiles.properties" prefix="profiles"/>

<echo>${profiles.CommercialManager}</echo>
```

Doing like this everything works fine, it prints out 
    MOT
But as you can see the value is not dynamic, is not the one taken from jenkins job..

So i should do something like this:

```
<echo>${ROLE}</echo>
```

But if I do something like this, the print returns the value of the property ROLE that is:

```
profiles.CommercialManager
```

and not the value taken from the properties file..

How can i manage this? I think its easy but, its late, and i swimming into a sea of confusion..

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to dynamically get a property value from a variable described in other threads:

- [In Ant, how can I dynamically build a property that references a property file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25674549/in-ant-how-can-i-dynamically-build-a-property-that-references-a-property-file)
- [Dynamic property names in ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263494/dynamic-property-names-in-ant)

Personally, I would use javascript:

```
<property file="Profiles.properties" prefix="profiles"/>

<script language="javascript"><![CDATA[
    project.setProperty("CommercialManager", project.getProperty("${Role}"))
]]>
</script>

<echo>${CommercialManager}</echo>
```